# How to predict a list of values in keras?

Tags: python, numpy, keras, regression

I would like to train a neural network with keras. The input data are multiple arrays with shape (1023, 256) and the labels are a list of 10 values for each input.
I expect a list with 10 Values as output.

I simplified my code:

```
input1 = np.random.rand(1023, 256)
input2 = np.random.rand(1023, 256)
label1 = np.random.rand(10)
label2 = np.random.rand(10)
test_data = np.random.rand(1023, 256)


inputs = np.stack((input1, input2))
labels = np.stack((label1, label2))

print(inputs.shape)
print(labels.shape)




model = Sequential()


model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(1023, 256), activation='relu'))


model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))


model.add(Dense(10, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')


model.fit(inputs, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)


predictions = model.predict(test_data)
```

The prediction should look something like this:

```
[ 8.06436593,  9.44189802, 10.44503002, 11.95312031, 14.43248845,
         3.63374982,  4.72397662,  5.54989524, 15.2114616 ,  7.70812219]
```

Output:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential_51" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 1023, 256), found shape=(None, 256)

Update:

```
input1 = np.random.rand(1023, 256)
input2 = np.random.rand(1023, 256)
label1 = np.random.rand(10)
label2 = np.random.rand(10)
test_data = np.random.rand(1, 1023, 256)


inputs = np.stack((input1, input2))
labels = np.stack((label1, label2))

print("Input shape: ", inputs.shape)
print("Label shape: ",labels.shape)




model = Sequential()


model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(1023, 256), activation='relu'))


model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))


model.add(Dense(10, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')


model.fit(inputs, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=0)


predictions = model.predict(test_data)

print(predictions.shape)
```

Output:

> Input shape:  (2, 1023, 256) Label shape:  (2, 10) 1/1
> [==============================] - 0s 83ms/step Prediction shape:
> (1, 1023, 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the batch dimension in your test data, since Keras will consider always the first axis as the batches. So test data must have the shape (1, 1023, 256) instead of (1023, 256).

```
test_data = np.expand_dims(test_data, axis=0)
predictions = model.predict(test_data)
```

I edited you model layers by adding Flatten before the last one (Dense 10) to get 1-dimensional data:

```
input1 = np.random.rand(1023, 256)
input2 = np.random.rand(1023, 256)
label1 = np.random.rand(10)
label2 = np.random.rand(10)
test_data = np.random.rand(1, 1023, 256)


inputs = np.stack((input1, input2))
labels = np.stack((label1, label2))

print("Input shape: ", inputs.shape)
print("Label shape: ",labels.shape)




model = Sequential()


model.add(Dense(256, input_shape=(1023, 256), activation='relu'))


model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(10, activation='linear'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

model.summary()
model.fit(inputs, labels, epochs=10, batch_size=1, verbose=1)


predictions = model.predict(test_data, batch_size=1)

print(predictions.shape)
```

Comment: But then the shape of the prediction output is: (1, 1023, 10). 
I just want a list with 10 values as output, like my label data.

Comment: You got this shape (1, 1023, 10) for your model or you just expected it?
Simply create your test_data as test_data = np.random.rand(1, 1023, 256). So here you will feed one batch with size 1 contained a data with shape (1023, 256) which was defined by your input layer. AND in predict function set batch_size=1.

Comment: I modified my code and the output of predictions.shape is (1, 1023, 10). 
Which I do not understand since my label data is (2, 10) so i expect the output to be in shape (1,10), because I want to predict an array with 10 values for each input (1, 1023, 10).

Comment: Would you kindly post your code edits so I can check them again.

Comment: edited my post with an update.

Comment: I added a Flatten layer to your model. Sorry I did not see it that you model is handling the input always as 2-dims, so you need to transfer it to 1-dim before the laster Dense layer. Also model.summary() helps in finding these kind of things :)